# How to get the object value on my text input?

Tags: javascript

```js
var fname = document.getElementById("fName");
var lname = document.getElementById("lName");
const btnSave = document.getElementById("btnSave");
const btnDisplay = document.getElementById("btnDisplay");

btnSave.addEventListener("click", getData);

function getData() {
  console.log(
    getFullName({
      fname: `${fname.value}`,
      lname: `${lname.value}`,
    })
  );
}

function getFullName(FullName) {
  return FullName.fname + " " + FullName.lname;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
    <button id="btnDisplay">Display</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How to get the object value on my text input?
It returns null. But when I assign value on my object like fName: "John", lName: "Doe"
It returns successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input elements do not have ids.

Answer (score 2):

"fname" and "lname" are not ids. You have incorrectly assigned types on your input fields. Instead do something like this:

```html
<input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add id to your input tags.

try :

```html
    <input id="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input id="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you html code by this
`<input type="text" id= "fName" placeholder="First Name" />`
`<input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />`

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign your INPUT tag an "id" or "class" and to get the value of an INPUT tag you must assign ".value" at the end of DOM target e.g

for **ID**    "document.getElementById("YOUR_ID NAME").value"

OR

for **CLASS** "document.getElementByClassName("YOUR_CLASS NAME").value"

```js
var fname = document.getElementById("fName");
var lname = document.getElementById("lName");
const btnSave = document.getElementById("btnSave");
const btnDisplay = document.getElementById("btnDisplay");

btnSave.addEventListener("click", getData);

function getData() {
  console.log(
    getFullName({
      firstname: fname.value,
      lastname: lname.value
    })
  );
}

function getFullName(FullName) {
  return FullName.firstname + " " + FullName.lastname;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="fName" type="fName" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input id="lName" type="lName" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <button id="btnSave">Save</button>
    <button id="btnDisplay">Display</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```